# What exactly are Javascript Timeout objects?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, dom-events

Here's a link with some sample code.

http://jsfiddle.net/4djNt/2/

I assumed, until I started testing, that the return value of a `setTimeout()` would be some kind of browser object.

In fact it seems to be a simple integer. I also believed that assigning the return value of `setTimeout` to a global variable would mean that there could only be one such object. But as you'll see if you click the "start timer" button more than one, there can be multiple timers running concurrently.

For instance

- I click the start button
- the script creates a timeout
- it is `timeout 1`, due to fire in five seconds
- one second later, I click again and now there's a `timeout 2`
- now I have `timeout 1` due to fire in four seconds and `timeout 2` in five seconds
- I click the stop button and only `timeout 2` is cleared

The problem of user clicks creating multiple timers can be solved by always clearing the current timeout var before setting it. But I would really like to understand what Javascript is doing actually doing here.

Comment: "But I would really like to understand what Javascript is doing actually doing here." --- you have explained it in your "For instance" list

Comment: The return value is sort of like a timer ID. To stop a particular timer, you run `clearTimeout(id)`.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) *"timeoutID is the numerical ID of the timeout, which can be used later with window.clearTimeout"*. When you assign it to the same global var, you are just overwriting the value

Comment: Imagine having an array `[...]` of all the timeouts. To access each one of them, JavaScript needs an *ID*, or the index of the timeout in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) return a number. The number is the `id` of the timer. Active timers can be stopped using [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) respectively.

If you lose the timer's id, you'd either have to guess it again, or wait for it to complete (assuming it's a timeout).

If the timer hasn't been cancelled in the number of milliseconds specified in the `delay` parameter, it will execute the callback function in the global context.

Comment: That makes sense. My mistake was assuming there was some kind of object, the way myWindow = window.open('foo') returns a reference to the window itself. Whatever object is created is totally private to the browser and we only get a number to identify it by.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel, exactly, it allows the browser to make the timers more efficient without having to do any javascript object management. If you *want* a timer object, you can certainly create a `Timer` constructor with `start` and `stop` methods.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `setTimeout` can be passed to `clearTimeout` to prevent a scheduled task from running. If the variable has been set and your button is pushed again, run `clearTimeout` first, then `setTimeout` assuming you want only the 2nd push to schedule.

Answer (score 2):

The questioner asks only about **timeout objects**, which are returned in lieu of numbers in some environments, for instance [`timeoutObject`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg).  For purposes of canceling the callback, passing the entire timeout object to `clearTimeout(toObj)` does the trick.

```
{
  called : bool
  _idleTimeout : null
  _idlePrev : null
  _idleNext : null
  _idleStart : null
  _onTimeout : function (){}
  _repeat : null
  unref : function () {}
  ref : function () {}
  close : function () {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be great if you could also explain where did you get that output from.